# Sharing a struct across header files

Tags: c, struct

I'm not sure how to correctly do this. I need to access a struct from another header file. I currently have 5 files. foo.h foo.c bar.h bar.c main.c.

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H_   /* include guard */
#define FOO_H_

typedef struct foostruct{
  int data;
} foostruct;

#endif
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"
// empty
```

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H_   /* include guard */
#define BAR_H_

typedef struct barstruct{
  int data;
  foostruct* foodata;
} barstruct;


#endif
```

bar.c

```
#include "bar.h"
#include "foo.h" // <-- thought i had to do it like this
// empty
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main () {
  printf("main\n");

  return 0;
}
```

compile error

```
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -c main.c foo.c bar.c
In file included from bar.c:1:0:
bar.h:6:3: error: unknown type name 'foostruct'
   foostruct* foodata;
   ^
make: *** [Makefile:22: main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Move the `#include "foo.h"` from `bar.c` to `bar.h`, remember that you must declare something before using it, so since `barstruct` uses `foostruct` then `foo.h` must be included before it. (Also you don't necessarily need to include `foo.h` in `main.c` since `bar.h` already includes it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change bar.h to:

```
typedef struct barstruct{
  int data;
  struct  foostruct* foodata;
} barstruct;
```

Note `struct foostruct *`

With this change, you dont need the dependancy of foo.h by bar.h.